# Can't bundle Angular 2 project with webpack

Tags: typescript, angular, webpack, angular2-build

I am trying to bundle my Angular 2 project in production mode with webpack but I see no dist folder being produced and I am getting the following errors-

> npm run build
>
> > angular2-webpack@1.0.0 build C:\Users\Rennie\Projects\tour_of_heroes
> >     rimraf dist && webpack --config config/webpack.prod.js --progress --profile --bail
> >                                                                                                                                                                                10% 0/3 build modulests-loader: Using typescript@1.8.10 and
> >     C:\Users\Rennie\Projects\tour_of_heroes\tsconfig.json
> >     17889918m11276ms optimize assets Hash: 7071423153409f1ffd44 Version:
> >     webpack 1.13.1 Time: 338789ms  [280] ./app/app.component.js 2.72 kB
> >     {0} [built]
> >            ... -> factory:62ms building:188ms dependencies:31ms  [313] ./app/suggestions.component.js 4.61 kB {0} [built]
> >            ... -> [280] 250ms -> factory:31ms building:2213ms dependencies:0ms  [314] ./app/suggestion.js 472 bytes {0} [built]
> >            ... -> [280] 250ms -> [313] 2244ms -> factory:1097ms building:4725ms  [315] ./app/suggestion.service.js 1.35 kB {0} [built]
> >            ... -> [280] 250ms -> [313] 2244ms -> factory:1097ms building:4725ms dependencies:0ms  [316] ./app/mock-suggestions.js 354
> >     bytes {0} [built]
> >            ... -> [280] 250ms -> [313] 2244ms -> [315] 5822ms -> factory:1748ms building:4998ms dependencies:0ms  [317]
> >     ./app/projects.component.js 3.35 kB {0} [built]
> >            ... -> [280] 250ms -> factory:31ms building:2322ms dependencies:0ms  [318] ./app/project.service.js 1.31 kB {0} [built]
> >            ... -> [280] 250ms -> [317] 2353ms -> factory:988ms building:4741ms dependencies:0ms  [319] ./app/mock-projects.js 443
> >     bytes {0} [built]
> >            ... -> [280] 250ms -> [317] 2353ms -> [318] 5729ms -> factory:1732ms building:4998ms  [320] ./app/project.js 424 bytes {0}
> >     [built]
> >            ... -> [280] 250ms -> [317] 2353ms -> [318] 5729ms -> [319] 6730ms -> factory:1226ms building:1816ms  [321] ./app/tech.service.js
> >     1.26 kB {0} [built]
> >            ... -> [280] 250ms -> [317] 2353ms -> factory:988ms building:4959ms dependencies:0ms  [322] ./app/mock-tech.js 710 bytes
> >     {0} [built]
> >            ... -> [280] 250ms -> [317] 2353ms -> [321] 5947ms -> factory:2276ms building:4268ms
> >         + 888 hidden modules
>
> WARNING in app.7071423153409f1ffd44.js from UglifyJs Condition always
>   true [./main.ts:5,4]
>
> WARNING in polyfills.7071423153409f1ffd44.js from UglifyJs Condition
>   always true [./polyfills.ts:4,4] Dropping unreachable code
>   [./polyfills.ts:8,2] Side effects in initialization of unused variable
>   anInstance [./~/core-js/modules/es6.number.to-fixed.js:3,0] Side
>   effects in initialization of unused variable anObject
>   [./~/core-js/modules/es6.promise.js:8,0] Side effects in
>   initialization of unused variable setProto
>   [./~/core-js/modules/es6.promise.js:12,0] Side effects in
>   initialization of unused variable hide
>   [./~/core-js/modules/_collection-strong.js:4,0] Side effects in
>   initialization of unused variable has
>   [./~/core-js/modules/es6.weak-map.js:8,0] Side effects in
>   initialization of unused variable TYPED_ARRAY
>   [./~/core-js/modules/es6.typed.array-buffer.js:9,0] Side effects in
>   initialization of unused variable parseInt
>   [./~/core-js/modules/_typed-buffer.js:24,0] Side effects in
>   initialization of unused variable min
>   [./~/core-js/modules/_typed-buffer.js:30,0] Side effects in
>   initialization of unused variable isInteger
>   [./~/core-js/modules/_typed-array.js:14,0] Side effects in
>   initialization of unused variable isIterable
>   [./~/core-js/modules/_typed-array.js:28,0] Condition left of || always
>   false [./~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:600,40] Condition left of || always
>   false [./~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:601,39] Dropping side-effect-free
>   statement [./~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:629,0] Side effects in
>   initialization of unused variable Zone
>   [./~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:152,0] Dropping unused variable
>   cacheSentinel [./~/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js:809,0] Condition always
>   false
>   [(webpack)/~/node-libs-browser/~/buffer/~/base64-js/lib/b64.js:124,1]
>
> WARNING in vendor.7071423153409f1ffd44.js from UglifyJs Dropping
>   unused variable __unused
>   [./~/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_injector.js:9,0] Side effects in
>   initialization of unused variable freeExports
>   [./~/rxjs/util/root.js:12,0] Side effects in initialization of unused
>   variable freeModule [./~/rxjs/util/root.js:13,0] Side effects in
>   initialization of unused variable SecurityContext
>   [./~/@angular/core/src/security.js:17,0] Side effects in
>   initialization of unused variable ViewType
>   [./~/@angular/core/src/linker/view_type.js:13,0] Dropping unused
>   variable __unused
>   [./~/@angular/core/src/platform_common_providers.js:10,0] Dropping
>   unused variable __unused
>   [./~/@angular/core/src/application_common_providers.js:8,0] Side
>   effects in initialization of unused variable ProviderAstType
>   [./~/@angular/compiler/src/template_ast.js:224,0] Side effects in
>   initialization of unused variable PropertyBindingType
>   [./~/@angular/compiler/src/template_ast.js:261,0] Side effects in
>   initialization of unused variable OPERATORS
>   [./~/@angular/compiler/src/expression_parser/lexer.js:422,0] Dropping
>   unused variable $FF [./~/@angular/compiler/src/html_lexer.js:69,0]
>   Dropping unused variable $$
>   [./~/@angular/compiler/src/html_lexer.js:75,0] Dropping unused
>   variable $QUESTION [./~/@angular/compiler/src/html_lexer.js:87,0]
>   Non-strict equality against boolean: != true
>   [./~/@angular/compiler/src/html_tags.js:295,0] Side effects in
>   initialization of unused variable TypeModifier
>   [./~/@angular/compiler/src/output/output_ast.js:12,0] Side effects in
>   initialization of unused variable BuiltinMethod
>   [./~/@angular/compiler/src/output/output_ast.js:268,0] Side effects in
>   initialization of unused variable StmtModifier
>   [./~/@angular/compiler/src/output/output_ast.js:502,0] Dropping unused
>   variable EVENT
>   [./~/@angular/compiler/src/schema/dom_element_schema_registry.js:12,0]
>   Dropping unused variable __unused
>   [./~/@angular/common/src/pipes/async_pipe.js:28,0] Non-strict equality
>   against boolean: == false
>   [./~/@angular/router-deprecated/src/router.js:532,0] Non-strict
>   equality against boolean: == false
>   [./~/@angular/router-deprecated/src/router.js:315,0] Dropping unused
>   variable __make_dart_analyzer_happy
>   [./~/@angular/router-deprecated/src/route_config/route_config_impl.js:7,0]
>   Side effects in initialization of unused variable RequestMethod
>   [./~/@angular/http/src/enums.js:14,0] Side effects in initialization
>   of unused variable ReadyState [./~/@angular/http/src/enums.js:28,0]
>   Side effects in initialization of unused variable ResponseType
>   [./~/@angular/http/src/enums.js:40,0]
>
> ERROR in
>   C:\Users\Rennie\Projects\tour_of_heroes\node_modules\reflect-metadata\Reflect.ts
>   (1406,33): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'msCrypto'.
>
> ERROR in
>   C:\Users\Rennie\Projects\tour_of_heroes\node_modules\reflect-metadata\Reflect.ts
>   (1407,21): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'msCrypto'.

My code does work on development mode.

My code can be found here at this repo-
[Portfolio Project](https://github.com/Renniesb/my_angular2_portfolio/tree/experimental)

Comment: Did you .gitignore your 'package.json' file? I do not see it. I will need it to reproduce this error.

Comment: There is no `package.json` file in your repository.

Comment: Please user proper format , i cant check your issue

Comment: There are few tslint warnings fixing them must help you. Update here so ppl are benefited

Answer (score 1):

Update your webpack version will solve this